# Giving multiple inputs in a same line until the user is done in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import re
time = input()
if re.match('^[1-2][0-9][:][0-9]{2}$',time):
    print('Late')
else:
    print('Ok')
```

I was working on a program in which there will be multiple timings (in 24 hour format. like 14:30,12:49 etc.) given by the user (the input range is from 4 to 9999) in a same line with a space between each of them. the problem is he doesn't give the number of inputs. He just types until he is done. so how to get the number of timings that are above 10:00. that says from 10:01.

the code i added only shows whether the time is above 10:00 or not. that too only for a single input. i am figuring out how to provide multiple inputs and run it where the all the inputs should be given in a single line

Comment: well i only managed to read whether the timing is above 10:00 or below to 10:00. i know how to give multiple inputs in a single line using split(). but don't know how to read them

Comment: import re
time = input()
if re.match('^[1-2][0-9][:][0-9]{2}$',time):
    print('Late')
else:
    print('Ok')

Comment: Put that code in the question and format it (put a ` before and after or use ctrl+k)

Comment: And explain what doesn't work.

Comment: the code i added only shows whether the time is above 10:00 or not. that too only for a single input. i am figuring out how to provide multiple inputs and run it where the all the inputs should be given in a single line.

Comment: You said you know you can use `split`. Why won't you split the input line and *then* use the regex?

Comment: yes. but it runs only once for a single input. how to make it run for all the timings in the same input line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

`input().split` will return a list of strings.

`[time for time in input.split() if re.match('^[1-2][0-9][:][0-9]{2}$',time)]` will return a list of strings from `input.split()` that match the RegEx.

`len([time for time in input.split() if re.match('^[1-2][0-9][:][0-9]{2}$',time)])` will return the number of such strings.

Comment: it worked. but actually i started learning python recently. so i didn't understand it. but it did work.

Comment: Read about list comprehension and lists in general, actually.

Comment: i got an another doubt on that. the program now shows the number of timings above 10:00 right. but it also includes 10:00 as well. how to make it work from 10:01 and leave 10:00 as okay

Comment: That is a regex thing, not a Python thing. I don't know regex so much so I can't help you. However, I could suggest you use the `datetime` module and not regex. I think it fits your problem much better.